# How do I execute Python file from SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent

I wrote a Trigger in SQL Server such that if values in one table updates, the trigger updates values in another table. I want a python script to kick off and push that updated data to SharePoint. I searched online but couldn't find anything that calls a Python script or ways to execute Python script right upon completion of a trigger. I know I can schedule the script but is there a way to kick off a job in SQL Server upon completion of a trigger? Thanks

Comment: Is there any need to pass data from the trigger to the Python script or do you just need to cause the script to execute promptly? I'm pondering using a _message queue_ as a way for the trigger to queue running the script without actually waiting for it to run. The Python side could wait for the arrival of a queued message.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the code below in the trigger to call a job (not scheduled) to run it and it works perfectly fine.

```
...
begin
 EXEC msdb..sp_start_job
 @job_name = 'JOB NAME';
end
```